# Change size of select box to match text box

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why there are two boxes in my nav.

If you take the Home for example, there are two boxes, one that holds the text of Home and one that protrudes to the right.

I want to shrink the protruding box to be the same as the text box that holds `Home, Projects, About Me and Resume` for cleanliness reasons and because when you hover to the right of the projects, the menu appears.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJjvWG?editors=1100#0

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: #4168a8;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 11px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

.title {
  color: #DB5461;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 35px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 35px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .4em;
  padding-left: .2em;
  padding-right: .2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.projects {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  width: 91px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  /* When you hover over items in dropdown */
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.underline_animation::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #222;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
}

.underline_animation:hover::after {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  visibility: visible;
}

.links {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 26px;
}

.links a {
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.links a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Belleza" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>mytitle</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">

      <nav>
        <a href="#" class="title">my title</a>
        <a>|</a>

        <li>
          <a href="#" class="underline_animation">home</a>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="projects">projects&nbsp; &#9662;</a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#" class="underline_animation">about me</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="files/resume.pdf" class="underline_animation">resume</a>
        </li>
      </nav>

      <div class="links">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <img src="images/linkedin_icon.png" height="25" width="25">
        </a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <img src="images/github_icon.png" height="25" width="25">
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you want can you depict it clearly in the comment ?? It's not clear what you want to say?

Comment: so you want the last two right side link to be in a single div(of home, projects...)?/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `margin-right: 0` to `nav li a` and set the `35px` margin it had to `nav li` - see demo below:

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: #4168a8;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 11px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 35px; /*ADDED THIS*/
}

.title {
  color: #DB5461;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 35px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 35px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .4em;
  padding-left: .2em;
  padding-right: .2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav li a { /*ADDED THIS*/
  margin-right: 0;
}

.projects {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  width: 91px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.dropdown:hover >.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  /* When you hover over items in dropdown */
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.underline_animation::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #222;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
}

.underline_animation:hover::after {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  visibility: visible;
}

.links {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 26px;
}

.links a {
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.links a:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Belleza" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>mytitle</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="container">

      <nav>
        <a href="#" class="title">my title</a>
        <a>|</a>

        <li>
          <a href="#" class="underline_animation">home</a>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="projects">projects&nbsp; &#9662;</a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#" class="underline_animation">about me</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="files/resume.pdf" class="underline_animation">resume</a>
        </li>
      </nav>

      <div class="links">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <img src="images/linkedin_icon.png" height="25" width="25">
        </a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <img src="images/github_icon.png" height="25" width="25">
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </header>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, legend! You fixed it